# How can I setRate for Android MediaPlayer?

Tags: android

How can I implement

```
setRate(float f)
```

for my Android MediaPlayer, and secondly is it posible?

Comment: MediaPlayer has a pretty simple interface.  You may need to use something else to adjust the playback rate.

Comment: did you found a solution?

Answer (score 4):

I believe [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack.html#setPlaybackRate%28int%29) is the function you are looking for.

This sets the sampling rate at which the audio data will be consumed and played back, not the original sampling rate of the content. Setting it to half the sample rate of the content will cause the playback to last twice as long, but will also result in a negative pitch shift. The valid sample rate range is from 1Hz to twice the value returned by `getNativeOutputSampleRate(int)`.

If you want to play mp3 directly using AudioTrack, you can either have a look at [this](http://mindtherobot.com/blog/624/android-audio-play-an-mp3-file-on-an-audiotrack/) example or convert your mp3 file to wav format, which enables AudioTrack to use it without hassle. This is the tradeoff you should account for if you want to adjust the playback rate easily.

Comment: Thanks, i try it, but with AudioTrack i can not play mp3 file from sdcard.

Comment: Yes, you can. You just need to read it into a buffer first and then write it to AudioTrack. Take a more careful look at how AudioTrack is used...

Answer (score 0):

Android 6.0 adds `PlaybackParams` for `MediaPlayer`, so you can now do this:

```
String recordingPath = recordingDirectory + File.separator + "music.mp3";
MediaPlayer audioPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), Uri.parse(recordingPath));
audioPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
PlaybackParams params = new PlaybackParams();
params.setSpeed(0.75f);
audioPlayer.setPlaybackParams(params);
audioPlayer.start();
```

I don't have an Android 6 device yet, but this works for me in the emulator.

Answer (score -2):

Based on the Android developer documentation, you may have to use SoundPool instead.

[Android Developer: Media SoundPool-setRate](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html#setRate%28int,%20float%29)

`public final void setRate (int streamID, float rate)`

> Change playback rate. The playback rate allows the application to vary
>   the playback rate (pitch) of the sound. A value of 1.0 means playback
>   at the original frequency. A value of 2.0 means playback twice as
>   fast, and a value of 0.5 means playback at half speed. If the stream
>   does not exist, it will have no effect.
>
> **Parameters**
>
> *streamID*:   a streamID returned by the play() function
>
> *rate*:   playback rate (1.0 = normal playback, range 0.5 to 2.0)

Comment: Thaks, but soundpool play file from application resources, and do not support seek function. In my app I want to play mp3 file from sdcard.

Comment: Soundpool playing only 5 seconds-files. It is not targeted for music